# Is NPAPI plug-in supported in CEF?

Tags: cefsharp, npapi

I create an application using C # (WinForms + Cefsharp Embedded Chromium). Now I want to add the NPAPI plug-in to my embedded Chromium to check the documents for authenticity. I know that Chrom has stopped supporting NPAPI due to security issues. Is it possible to include NPAPI support in CEF or should I look for other ways to solve my problem?

Comment: No, hasn't been supported in years.